# efficient way of subtracting 2 dataframes in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have 2 dataframes : data and ineligible with the below shapes:

```
 print(data.shape)
```

(72757056, 5)

```
print(ineligible.shape)
```

(141531, 2)

these 2 datafrmaes have 2 columns in common ("barcode" and "store")
What I want to do is to drop the rows of "data" which the combination of barcode and store are not in "ineligible" and I know that I can get the result by below code:

```
data = data[~(data.loc[:,["barcode"] + (data.loc[:,"store"]).astype(str)).isin((ineligible.loc[:,"barcode"] + (ineligible.loc[:,"store"]).astype(str)))]
```

however since the length of the "data" is so huge, I ran out of memory (16 GB) and fail to get the results. 
I appreciate if someone could provide me with a more efficient and less memory usage solution.

suppose the sample dataframes looks like below:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'barcode': ['A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C','A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C'],'store': ['P5', 'P2', 'P3', 'P4', 'P5','P2','P4','P1','P1','P2'],'count1': [0,5,7,8,0,1,8,0,0,9],'count2': [0,5,7,8,0,1,8,0,0,9]})

ineligible = pd.DataFrame({'barcode': ['A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C'],'store': ['P1', 'P2', 'P3', 'P4', 'P5']})
```

and the result should look like below:
[image: result]

Comment: It might be easier if you can provide a sample dataframe, such that people can test their attempt and make sure it generates the results you want.

Comment: You wrote that you wanted to drop rows where **combination** of *barcode* and *store* is not in "ineligible".
Note that e.g. such combination as "A / P5" is **absent** in *ineligible*,
so there is a contradiction between what you wrote and your expected result.

Answer (score 3):

Using numpy broadcasting here. It should be a lot faster since it's vectorized C code.

```
barcodes = data['barcode'].values
stores = data['store'].values

ineligible_barcodes = ineligible['barcode'].values[:, None]
ineligible_stores = ineligible['store'].values[:, None]

ineligible_codes = np.any((barcodes == ineligible_barcodes) & (stores == ineligible_stores), axis=0)
data[~ineligible_codes]
```

Result:

```
  barcode store  count1  count2
0       A    P5       0       0
5       A    P2       1       1
6       B    P4       8       8
7       B    P1       0       0
8       C    P1       0       0
9       C    P2       9       9
```

Comment: can you please a little bit elaborate on why you used "values[:, None]" for "ineligible_barcodes" and "ineligible_stores"? thanks in advance

Comment: I also get the below error, when I try your solution on my real data set: _main__:1: DeprecationWarning: elementwise comparison failed; this will raise an error in the future.

Answer (score 1):

My idea is to do **in place** the following operations:

- Set the index in *data* to *['barcode', 'store']*.
- Drop rows of *data* where the current index is absent in the (Multi)Index
  created from *barcode* and *store* columns in *ineligible*.
- Change *barcode* and *store* back to "regular" columns.

The code to do it is:

```
data.set_index(['barcode', 'store'], inplace=True)
data.drop(data.index.difference(pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(ineligible)), inplace=True)
data.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

To test it, I used the following DataFrames:

```
data                        ineligible

  barcode store  val          barcode store
0    1111    22   10        0    1111    22
1    1112    22   12        1    1112    22
2    1112    33   13        2    1112    44
3    1115    22   14        3    1115    22
4    1115    33   15        4    1115    44
5    1118    34   16        5    1118    34
6    1118    35   17        6    1130    33
7    1119    33   18
```

getting the following result:

```
  barcode store  val
0    1111    22   10
1    1112    22   12
2    1115    22   14
3    1118    34   16
```

## Edit following the comment

If you want to drop rows where the combination of barcode and store **is**
in "ineligible", change the "middle" instruction to:

```
data.drop(data.index.intersection(pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(ineligible)), inplace=True)
```

Comment: what I intended was the opposite of result you have provided. I want the "barcode", "store" of ineligible dataframe, being excluded from data dataframe.

Comment: In your post you wrote: *drop the rows of "data" which the combination of ... are **not** in "ineligible"*.
This is in contradiction to your comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can perform a merge and keep only the rows from the first dataframe:

```
data_merged=pd.merge(data,ineligible, on=['barcode','store'],how='left',indicator=True)
data_eligible_only=data_merged.loc[data_merged['_merge']=='left_only']
```

Comment: that worked but I still have trouble with memory issue with your approach.